# Vue Js - focusing on element programatically

Tags: vue.js

I am brand new to using VueJs (first day!)

I want to validate an email field, and return focus to the email inut if not valid. I am using the watch property (see below), and although I can successfully watch value changes, I am not able to set focus back to the email field.

What am I doing wrong?

#### Code snippet

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title>V3 Example</title>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>        
    </head>
    <style type="text/css">
        form input, form button {
            display: block;
            margin: 3px;
        }
    </style>

    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <form @submit.prevent >
                <h3></h3>
                <input type="username" v-model="username" />
                <input ref="email" type="email" v-model="email" />
                <input type="password" v-model="passwd" autocomplete="off"/>
                <button @click="logIt" >Login </button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <script>
            let app = Vue.createApp({
                data() {
                    return {
                        username: '',
                        email: '',
                        passwd: '',
                    }
                },

                methods: {
                    logIt() {                        
                        console.log('here!');
                    }
                },

                watch: {

                    email(val1, val2){
                        if (!val2.includes('@')) {
                            this.$refs.email.focus(); // <- this is supposed to return focus to email input
                            console.log('Not valid email!');
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log(val1);
                            console.log(val2);                            
                        }
                    }

                }
            })

            app.mount('#app');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
this.$refs.email.$el.focus();
```

Comment: According to the Vue documentation, that syntax is only required if being used by a child component, and the reference `email` is declared/defined in the parent (containing) component.  See this [link](https://michaelnthiessen.com/set-focus-on-input-vue)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works, I've added a method `onSubmit` which is called when the form submits and inside it I validate email field, and focus it if is not valid. The key here is `nextTick` which makes sure to wait before Vue does any DOM update it needs before focusing the element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>V3 Example</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>        
</head>
<style type="text/css">
    form input, form button {
        display: block;
        margin: 3px;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <form @submit.prevent="onSubmit" >
            <h3></h3>
            <input type="username" v-model="username" />
            <input ref="email" type="email" v-model="email" />
            <input type="password" v-model="passwd" autocomplete="off"/>
            <button @click="logIt" >Login </button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script>
        let app = Vue.createApp({
            data() {
                return {
                    username: '',
                    email: '',
                    passwd: '',
                }
            },

            methods: {
                logIt() {                        
                    console.log('here!');
                                    },
                                    onSubmit() {
                                        if (!this.email.includes('@')) {
                                            this.$nextTick(() => { // must wait for next tick before interacting with DOM
                                                this.$refs.email.focus();
                                                console.log('Not valid email!');
                                            })
                                        }
                                    }
            },

            watch: {

                email(val1, val2){
                    if (!val2.includes('@')) {
                        this.$refs.email.focus(); // <- this is supposed to return focus to email input
                        console.log('Not valid email!');
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log(val1);
                        console.log(val2);                            
                    }
                }

            }
        })

        app.mount('#app');
    </script>
</body>
```